# Store multiple credentials in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

Is it possible to store multiple credentials for a given user in Keycloak?

They don't need to be all active/enabled at the same time. The use case for us is rather that we want to store new credentials in advance but don't want to have them active yet. They should be activated/enabled at a later time after some manual user verification.

The [Keycloak REST API documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.2/rest-api/index.html#_userrepresentation) states that `UserRepresentation` *indeed* comprises an **array** of `CredentialRepresentation` but in my few tests the `GET` call wouldn't even return a `credentials` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that's **impossible** to have more credentials for a user.

But you can always implement your **own user storage SPI** that implements interface `CredentialInputValidator`, where you can check for the valid password.

Let's say in your DB, you have 2 colums for passwords: `pas_col1` and `pas_col2`, and 1 more column as `flag`, which tells what column is used for user authentication, so in `isValid(RealmModel realm, UserModel user, CredentialInput input)` method you can check for your conditions.

Link to SPI: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.4/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi